# Replace array elements based on another array (kinda like excel vlookup)

Tags: python, numpy

I want to replace each element of my array (array A) with a list,
based on the value of the first element of the list set in the reference array.
It's kinda look like excel vlookup.
But currently I dont have pandas library in my machine,
can you tell me the solution by just using numpy.
Please help me...

This is what I have :

```
>>>A=np.array([[[4],
                [2],
                [3],
                [1]],
               [[2],
                [1],
                [3],
                [3]]])
        
    
>>>ref=np.array([[1,111,111,111],
                 [2,222,222,222],
                 [3,333,333,333],
                 [4,444,444,444]])
```

This is my goal:

```
          [[[4,444,444,444],
            [2,222,222,222],
            [3,333,333,333],
            [1,111,111,111]],
           [[2,222,222,222],
            [1,111,111,111],
            [3,333,333,333],
            [3,333,333,333]]]
```

I have used the solution from @Daniel F ,`ref[A.squeeze() - 1]` and it worked.
But if array A and ref I edit as follows.

```
>>>A=np.array([[[4000],        >>>ref=np.array([[1,111,111,111],
                   [2],                         [2,222,222,222],
                   [3],                         [3,333,333,333],
                   [1]],                        [4000,444,444,444]])
                  [[2],
                   [1],
                   [3],
                   [3]]])
```

The result is an error.

```
IndexError: index 3999 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 8
```

Is there a more flexible solution?

Comment: well, for one `ref[A-1]` works . . .

Comment: thank you for your answer. this is very helpful.
The size of the solution is (2,4,1,4), what I expect is (2,4,4).
But with ref [A-1] [:,:, 0,:], it becomes OK. @Daniel F

Comment: or `ref[A.squeeze() - 1]`

Comment: I edited array A and ref, but an error appears as described above, do you have any other solutions? @Daniel F